# Terminate X11 Application with Mouse

Tags: x11, process, desktop-shortcuts

There is a feature in X11 that temporarily transforms your mouse pointer into a *"kill X11 application"* icon (I don't even know what to call it) and allows you to forcibly terminate a process that owns an X11 window.  On occasion I've activated this feature accidentally and want to be able to do this consistently.

What is the keyboard, mouse shortcut, or other means of activating this feature?  How does it work? is it a legacy feature and/or only works under some environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's `xkill`. It is shipped with [Xorg](https://www.x.org/releases/individual/app/), which is the standard X11 server, so likely you already have it installed.

In any window manager or desktop environment, you can associate a shortcut with a command. The way that is done varies, look into the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, and I found the shortcut, under KDE the default binding is _Ctrl+Alt+Esc_ and it is found under Global Shortcuts → KWin → Kill Window